# Is my SELECT query wrong?

Tags: php, xml, select

Hei , I'm trying to verify if my username and password from my xml file is the same with those from my database, but mysql_num_rows is zero. So something must be wrong with my SELECT query.
This is my code:

```
 public function verifyDB()
{
   //connection to database
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('proiect_is') or die(mysql_error());

     $data =mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE userName ='$this->xml->parameters->username' AND password ='$this->xml->parameters->pass'");
    //we check if any row was returned
    echo $data;
     echo $this->xml->parameters->username."<BR>";
     echo $this->xml->parameters->pass."<BR>";
     print_r(mysql_num_rows($data));
    if (mysql_num_rows($data))
    {

       $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
       $this->_id= $row['id'];
       echo $row;
       return true;
    }
    else
    {return false;}

}
```

This is my xml login file:

```
 <xml version="">
  <action>log_in</action>
  <parameters>
    <username>Ionel P</username>
<pass>abdef01</pass>
  </parameters>
 </xml>
```

Comment: What was the output of `echo $data;`?

Comment: Make sure you have your table field names correct in your query; mysql is case sensitive if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$data =mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE userName ='".$this->xml->parameters->username."' AND password ='".$this->xml->parameters->pass."'");
```

Answer (score 8):

if you're inserting variables in a string, you should use `{}` like this:

```
"SELECT id FROM users WHERE userName ='{$this->xml->parameters->username}' AND password ='{$this->xml->parameters->pass}'"
```

this tells the parser to insert the variable `$this->xml->parameters->username` where it otherwise only tries to use `$this` (and leaves `->xml->parameters->username` as text wich ends up in "*[toString-Text of your Object]->xml->parameters->username*" wich is obviously wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
$data =mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE userName ='$this->xml->parameters->username' AND password ='$this->xml->parameters->pass'");
echo mysql_error();
```

return any errors? this should give you a good indication of where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
$data =mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT id FROM users WHERE userName ='%s' AND password ='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($this->xml->parameters->username), mysql_real_escape_string($this->xml->parameters->pass)));
```